# How to get instances configuration deployed in Ali cloud?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

Our customer using Alibaba cloud to deploy their application. They rented dozens of VMs/instances. We are asked to using API to get instance configuration (i.e. number of core, memory, network bandwidth, SSD, disk type, zone and etc) by program. We have found Ali open APIs in github./1/

Could someone point out which exact API could we call to get instance configuration?

/1/ https://github.com/aliyun/aliyun-openapi-java-sdk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DescribeInstanceAttribute](https://help.aliyun.com/document_detail/105518.html) API. I feel it's very helpful to use the [APIExplorer](https://api.aliyun.com/?product=Ecs&api=DescribeInstanceAttribute&params=%7B"RegionId":"","InstanceId":""%7D&tab=DEMO&lang=JAVA) to debug APIs. You don't need to install SDKs, CLIs, write any code, and configure access keys etc. Just login your Alibaba Cloud account, fill in some inputs, and click the **Send Request**. Everything is there!

[image]